# Replacing OpenSSL v1.1.1f with v1.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, openssl

I need my application to run in FIPS compliant mode. At the moment the only supported OpenSSL version with FIPS compliance is v1.0.2. On the other side default OpenSSL version on Ubuntu 20.04 is 1.1.1f.

If my understanding is correct, some applications from official repository that depends on OpenSSL ( like OpenSSH, cmake, etc ) were dynamically compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1f and therefore I can't just replace v1.1.1f with v1.0.2g because I will likely run into ABI incompatibility issues.

I have two questions:

Is my understanding correct?
Does that mean I have to recompile all applications that dynamically links to OpenSSL ( from ubuntu repo ) with OpenSSL v1.0.2?

Comment: What's stopping you from building OpenSSL 1.0.2 as a static library and having your application link with that directly?

Comment: That is an option but there is a problem to overcome with static linkage with OpenSSL FIPS. FIPS mode intialization failed!                                                                                                                                                                                    FIPS_mode_set failed: 2d06b06f.error:2D06B06F:lib(45):func(107):reason(111)

Comment: Another reason is that eventually I need other applications to use FIPS enabled openssl as well.

Comment: There is no reason why you can't have a 1.0.2 build alongside the system 1.1.1f version. You will at least need to recompile your application and fix any incompatibility issues. At runtime you will need to make sure your library path is appropriately set to pick up the 1.0.2 libraries instead of the system 1.1.1f libraries. This way you can leave the rest of the system alone, and only worry about those applications that actually need to use 1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your application to be FIPs compliant, you need not only OpenSSL, but you also need complient OS. As I know at least for now, FIPS variant for Ubuntu 20.04 is not still available. So even if you solve it technically, your application will not be FIPs compliant unless you certify the Ubuntu 20.04 by yourself.